# Converting list of dictionaries into Dataframe in sane way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The zendesk api returns fields as a list of dictionaries but each list is a single record.  I'm wondering if there is a better way to turn it all into a dataframe.  If it's a dictionary of dictionaries then `json_normalize` takes care of it with no problem.

Caveat: not all records will have the same field IDs

Sample data:

```
data = [{
  "ticket_id": 4,
  "customer_id": 8,
  "created_at": "2022-05-01",
  "custom_fields": [
    {
      "id": 15,
      "value": "website"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "value": "broken"
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "value": None
    },
  ],
  'group_id': 42
}]
```

Running any form of Dataframe, `from_records`, `from_json`, or `json_normalize` gives most of what I want but with the list in a single column:

```
t_df = pd.json_normalize(data)
t_df
```

Output:

|  | ticket_id | customer_id | created_at | custom_fields | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 8 | 2022-05-01 | [{'id': 15, 'value': 'website'}, {'id': 16, 'v... | 42 |

My current, probably ill-advised, solution is:

```
t_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_df.at[0, 'custom_fields']).T.reset_index(drop=True)
t_df.rename(columns=t_df.iloc[0], inplace=True)
t_df.drop(0, inplace=True)
t_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
pd.merge(left=sample_df, left_index=True,
         right=t_df, right_index=True).drop(columns='custom_fields')
```

This results in a correct record that I could append to a main dataframe:

|  | ticket_id | customer_id | created_at | group_id | 15 | 16 | 23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 8 | 2022-05-01 | 42 | website | broken | None |

My worry is that i need to do this to ~25,000 records and this seems like it will be both slow and brittle (prone to breaking).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrangle the data/dictionary first and only then construct a DataFrame with it. It will make your life easier and is faster than trying to manipulate the data with `pandas` i.e. after the DataFrame is created.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{
  "ticket_id": 4,
  "customer_id": 8,
  "created_at": "2022-05-01",
  "custom_fields": [
    {
      "id": 15,
      "value": "website"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "value": "broken"
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "value": None
    },
  ],
  'group_id': 42
}]

custom_fields = data[0].pop('custom_fields')
data[0].update({rec['id']: rec['value'] for rec in custom_fields})

t_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> t_df 

   ticket_id  customer_id  created_at  group_id       15      16    23
0          4            8  2022-05-01        42  website  broken  None
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks @Rodalm.  This works way faster.  ~2800 records only takes about 3 seconds on my Macbook Pro.  So extrapolating out even a full run should be less than a minute or so.

Comment: Additional learning: Iterate through each record doing the pop/update thing.  THEN turn the whole thing into a dataframe.  I was turning each record into a dataframe then using concat to append it to the existing main dataframe.  This got progressively slower as it makes a copy of the whole dataframe for every concat.

Comment: @DChaps No problem, I'm happy to help ;) That is indeed an excellent tip and improvement! I was going to suggest that as well, but it's even better you figured it out by yourself! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It looks like pandas isn't automatically determining which fields are "metadata" and which are "records" --> if your data is fixed, I would recommend hardcoding the following:

```py
>>> t_df = pd.json_normalize(
...     data,
...     meta=["ticket_id", "customer_id", "created_at", "group_id"],
...     record_path=["custom_fields"]
... )

   id    value ticket_id customer_id  created_at group_id
0  15  website         4           8  2022-05-01       42
1  16   broken         4           8  2022-05-01       42
2  23     None         4           8  2022-05-01       42
```

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{
  "ticket_id": 4,
  "customer_id": 8,
  "created_at": "2022-05-01",
  "custom_fields": [
    {
      "id": 15,
      "value": "website"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "value": "broken"
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "value": None
    },
  ],
  'group_id': 42
}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for index in df.index:
    for i in df.loc[index,'custom_fields']:
        df.loc[index,i['id']] = i['value']
df.drop(columns = 'custom_fields',inplace = True)
df
```